# Java - need help untangling compact Java notations: orElse, Optional, Lazy

Tags: java

I'm attempting to understand what's happening in this bit of Java code as its owner are no longer around and possibly fixing it or simplifying it. I'm guessing these blocks had a lot more in them at some point and what's left in place was not cleaned up properly.
It seems all occurrences of `orElse(false)` don't set anything to `false` and can be removed.
Then the second `removeDiscontinued` method is returning a boolean that I don't think is used anywhere. Is this just me or this is written in a way that makes it hard to read?
I'm hesitant removing anything from it since I haven't used much of the syntax like orElse, Lazy, Optional. Some help would be much appreciated.

```java
private void removeDiscontinued(Optional<Map<String, JSONArrayCache>> dptCache, Lazy<Set<String>> availableTps) {
    dptCache.map(pubDpt -> removeDiscontinued(pubDpt.keySet(), availableTps)).orElse(false);
}

private boolean removeDiscontinued(Set<String> idList, Lazy<Set<String>> availableTps) {
    if (availableTps.get().size() > 0) {
        Optional.ofNullable(idList).map(trIds -> trIds.removeIf(id -> !availableTps.get().contains(id)))
                .orElse(false);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `orElse(...)` takes effect iff. the `Optional` is `empty()`. It is used instead of a `null`-check. We could rewrite it like this: `private void removeDiscontinued(Map<String, JSONArrayCache> dptCache, Lazy<Set<String>> availableTps) { if (dptCache == null) { return false; } return removeDiscontinued(dptCache.keySet(), availableTps)).orElse(false); }`

Comment: Yes, the orElse is indeed redundant if the result is unused. But then you also should't use map but ifPresent. In general this code is very poorly written too, because using Optional as a parameter type and having nullable collection types is frowned upon.

Comment: @Clashsoft I agree with `Optional` as parameter beinig a smell on **public** methods. For private methods, however, I feel that it simplifies some flows (`.map(...)` is not always possible, and explicit unwrapping and re-wrapping is just boilerplate).

Comment: Turing85 - Thank you, yes, I see that explicit null test, and not optional, simplifies it and makes it a lot more readable. Clashsoft  - thank you for the suggestion on ifPresent, I'm going to try that out as well. BIG thank you to both of you!

Answer (score 5):

This code is indeed extremely silly. I know why - there's a somewhat common, extremely misguided movement around. This movement makes claims that are generally interpreted as 'write it 'functional' and then it is just better'.

That interpretation is obvious horse exhaust. It's just not true.

We can hold a debate on who is to blame for this - is it folks hearing the arguments / reading the blogposts and drawing the wrong conclusions, or is it the 'functional fanfolks' fanning the flames, so to speak, making ridiculous claims that do not hold up?

Point is: This code is using functional style when it is utterly inappropriate to do so and it has turned into a right mess as a result. The code is definitely bad; the author of this code is not a great programmer, but perhaps most of the blame goes to the functional evangelistst. At any rate, it's very difficult to read; no wonder you're having a hard time figuring out what this stuff does.

### The fundamental issue

The fundamental issue is that this functional style **strongly** likes being a side-effect free process: You start with some data, then the functional pipeline (a chain of stream map, orElse, etc operations) produces some new result, and then you do something with that. Nothing within the pipeline should be changing anything, it's just all in service of calculating new things.

**Both of your methods fail to do so properly** - the return value of the 'pipeline' is ignored in both of them, it's all about the side effects.

You don't want this: The primary point of the pipelines is that they can skip steps, and will aggressively do so if they think they can, and the pipeline assumes no side-effects, so it makes wrong calls.

That `orElse` is **not actually optional** - it doesn't seem to do anything, except: It *forces* the pipeline to run, except the spec doesn't quite guarantee that it will, so this code is in that sense flat out broken, too.

These methods also take in `Optional` as an argument type which is completely wrong. Optional is okay as a return value for a functional pipeline (such as `Stream`'s own `max()` etc methods). It's debatable as a return value anywhere else, and it's flat out silly and a style error so bad you should configure your linter to aggressively flag it as not suitable for production code if they show up in a field declaration or as a method argument.

So get rid of that too.

### Let's break down what these methods do

Both of them will call `map` on an Optional. An optional is either 'NONE', which is like null (as in, there is no value), or it is a SOME, which means there is exactly one value.

Both of your methods invoke `map` on an optional. This operation more or less boils down, in these specific methods, as:

*If the optional is NONE, do nothing, silently. Otherwise, perform the operation in the parens*.

Thus, to get rid of the `Optional` in the argument of your first method, just remove that, and then update the calling code so that it decides what to do in case of no value, instead of this pair of methods (which decided: If passing in an optional.NONE, silently do nothing. "Silently do nothing" is an extremely stupid default behaviour mode, which is a large part of why Optional is not great). Clearly it has an Optional from somewhere - either it made it (with e.g. `Optional.ofNullable` in which case undo that too, or it got one from elsewhere, for example because it does a stream operation and that returned an optional, in which case, replace:

```
Optional<Map<String, JSONArrayCache>> optional = ...;
removeDiscontinued(thatOptionalThing, availableTps);
```

with:

```
optional.map(v -> removeDiscontinued(v, availableTps));
```

or perhaps simply:

```
if (optional.isPresent()) {
    removeDiscontinued(optional.get(), availableTps);
} else {
    code to run otherwise
}
```

If you don't see how it could be null, great! Optional is significantly worse than NullPointerException in many cases, and so it is here as well: You do **NOT** want your code to silently do nothing when some value is absent in a place where the programmer of said code wasn't aware of that possibility - an exception is vastly superior: You then know there is a problem, and the exception tells you where. In contrast to the 'silently do not do anything' approach, where it's much harder to tell something is off, and once you realize something is off, you have no idea where to look. Takes literally hundreds of times longer to find the problem.

Thus, then just go with:

```
removeDiscontinued(thatOptionalThing.get(), availableTps);
```

which will NPE if the unexpected happens, which is good.

### The methods themselves

Get rid of those pipelines, functional is not the right approach here, as you're only interested in the side effects:

```
private void removeDiscontinued(Map<String, JSONArrayCache> dptCache, Lazy<Set<String>> availableTps) {
    Set<String> keys = dptCache.keySet();
    if (availableTps.get().size() > 0) {
        keys.removeIf(id -> availableTps.get().contains(id));
    }
}
```

That's it - that's all you need, that's what that code does in a very weird, sloppy, borderline broken way.

Specifically:

- That `boolean` return value is just a red herring - the author needed that code to return *something* so that they could use it as argument in their `map` operation. The value is completely meaningless. If a styleguide that promises: "Your code will be better if you write it using this style" ends up with extremely confusing pointless variables whose values are irrelevant, get rid of the style guide, I think.
- The `ofNullable` wrap is pointless: That method is private and its only caller cannot possibly pass null there, unless `dptCache` is an instance of some bizarro broken implementation of the Map interface that deigns to return `null` when its `keySet()` method is invoked: If that's happening, definitely fix the problem at the source, don't work around it in your codebase, no sane java reader would expect `.keySet` to return null there. That `ofNullable` is just making this stuff hard to read, it doesn't do anything here.
- Note that the `if (availableTps.get().size() > 0)` check is just an optimization. You can leave it out if you want. That optimization isn't going to have any impact unless that dptCache object is a large map (thousands of keys at least).

Comment: this is truly the answer that addresses all of the difficulties I'm having with this block. I don't like ambiguity, and what you're proposing is clean and straight forward. I very much appreciate you taking the time to point out the issues in this Java block.